# Почему сервис angular кешируется?

Tags: typescript, angular

Я делаю калькулятор. Сейчас пытаюсь разделить логику, чтобы юыло проще редактировать и расширять свой калькулятор.
Столнулся с одной проблемой, она не должна возникать в принцепи. Не могу найти причину.

Пример:
Есть основной сервис, который что то считает

first.service.ts

```
basefunction(obj) {
   var result = this.childrenservice.somefunction(obj);
   console.log(result)
}
```

children.service.ts

```
somefunction(obj) {
    obj['Inventory'] = this.Inventory; //делает копию объекта
    for (let y in details.Inventory) {
      details.Inventory[y]['count'] = 1; // Создает елемент равным 1
    }
   details.Inventory['ItogMonth'] = 123123; // Добавляем какой то итог.
}
```

При первом вызове функции нет проблем, создаются в первый раз елементы ItogMonth и count итп.
Но при новом вызове дочерней функции она уже имеет элемент ItogMonth и возникает ошибка, 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'count' on number '123123'

хотя в obj не содержит ItogMonth. Делаю вывод что он кешируется где то в оперативной памяти. Почему это происходит?

Comment: почитайте документацию по dependency injection в angular и все вопросы отпадут, к тому же `obj['Inventory'] = this.Inventory` - это не копия объекта

Comment: Спасиб о за наводку,  dependency injection - прочитал, не понял, перечитал опять же не понял. По этой части проблем не увидел, а вто в создании копии это в точку.
Я создаю ссылку и изменяю this.Inventory. Спасибо